# how to Sending SMS through VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I tried to send sms 
it was using textlocal.in
this is the code i tried

```
Public Function SendSms(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim apikey = txtAPI.Text
    Dim message = txtMsg.Text
    Dim numbers = txtNum.Text
    Dim strPOST As String
    Dim senderName = txtSend.Text
    Dim url As String = "https://api.textlocal.in/send/?"

    strPOST = url + "apikey=" + apikey _
    + "&numbers=" + numbers _
    + "&message=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(message) _
    + "&sender=" + sender

    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strPOST)
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strPOST)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()

    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
    Console.ReadLine()

    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

    If responseFromServer.Length > 0 Then
        Return responseFromServer
    Else
        Return CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription
    End If
End Function
```

it is saying Operator '+' is not defined for string "https://api.textlocal.in/send/?a" and type 'Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code `sender` is the Button that raises the event:

```
Public Function SendSms(sender As Object
                        ^^^^^^
```

It is not the phone number of the person sending the message. Replace `sender` with `senderName` on this line:

```
strPOST = url + "apikey=" + apikey _
+ "&numbers=" + numbers _
+ "&message=" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(message) _
+ "&sender=" + sender
               ^^^^^^^
```

Do not use `+` to concatenate strings in vb unless you know [exactly what it is doing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/concatenation-operators)

Use `&` to concatenate strings, but in this case I would recommend you use [string formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: acually in api intergration they are using + link(https://www.textlocal.in/free-developer-sms-api/)

Comment: *They are using `+`* - that is not true; I clicked that link you gave and immediately saw a screenshot that uses `&` to concat the string. *Microsoft's* advice is not to use `+` to concatenate strings in VB unless you understand what it does and how it differs from `&`. Read the link I made under the text "exactly what it is doing" - here's an excerpt: *The + Operator has the primary purpose of adding two numbers ... **The & operator is recommended for string concatenation** because ....* - Microsoft's words, not mine.

Comment: And actually your code would be a lot more readable if you'd use string interpolation: `$"apikey={apikey}&numbers={numbers}&message={WebUtility.UrlEncode(message)}&sender={senderName}"`